# Group combinations with different group capacities

Tags: algorithm

Well, I have a question about what algorithm would be most appropriate for my problem. Let's say that I have 3 groups:

```
Group A) 1 2 3 
Group B) 5 4
Group C) 9 6 7 8
```

Now I would like to get all possible groups with this members (1-8) and groups with capacity 3, 2, 4.

Note:

```
Group A) 3 1 2
Group B) 5 4
Group C) 7 8 9 6
```

counts as the same group combination as above combination.

I tried with all possible combinations of this numbers (1-8) but knowing that I might have a groups with total of 30 members I would came up with 265252859812191058636308480000000 different combinations, but that is too many.

I tried to search for non-isomorphics groups, but had no luck.

Comment: Hang on – '3' is duplicated in your first example, and '5' is duplicated in your second example.  Is that correct?

Comment: There are 6190283353629375 ways to pair up 30 people. Do you really want all of them?

Comment: John: thanks, I misstyped ...
Dave: Actually I probably need all of them. I need to find best group combination - with fewest conflicts. Lets say that element 6 hates element 9, so I need to find best combination to achieve minimal conflicts in group combination.

Comment: Unless you have only a few big groups, enumerating all of them will likely take way too long. Could you add more details?

Comment: John: No, I am just trying to solve a homework in a most elegant way. 
Dave: I would need to calculate groups with up to 100 members so yes, it would took a lot of time, but is not a problem if algorithm would be able to calculate most appropriate combination in less than, lets say, 5 hours ... What details were you thinking of?

Comment: We're talking longer than the life of the universe with 100 members. There's a lot of accumulated knowledge about combinatorial optimization, but we can't help you if we don't know the whole problem.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that no numbers can be entered twice (you have two 3's in your first example, and two 5's in your second...), so I'll just be using numbers 1-9 and the same number of elements in each group.

Depending on how well you know combinatorics, you will understand more or less of this - if you don't understand, please ask and I'll do my best to explain in more detail.

Your problem is a pretty standard one - you want to divide a set of 9 elements into subsets of 3, 2 and 4 elements respectively. This is known as a [multinomial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Combinatorics#Partitions)*, and is calculated as so:

```
n = 9! / (3!*2!*4!)
```

Basically, what you do is this:

1) choose 3 elements for group A: `n1 = 9 choose 3.`
2) choose 2 elements for group B: `n2 = 6 choose 2.`
3) the remaining four elements are group C.

Total:

```
n = n1 * n2 = 9!/(3!6!) * 6!/(2!4!) = 9! / (3!*2!*4!)
```

*) See the section about "Partitions"

**EDIT:** I noticed something about special requirements (6 hates 9, for instance) in a comment to the question. If you have such, see to them first (place the 9 in one group, 6 in one of the other two) and then see to the leftovers.